# How to instantiate templates from mpl::vector?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl

How a can transform vector of stl containers?

I have:

```
typedef boost::mpl::vector<std::vector<boost::mpl::_1>, std::deque<boost::mpl::_1> > Containers;
```

Heed to transform it to:

```
typedef boost::mpl::vector<std::vector<int>, std::deque<int> > IntContainers;
```

How to do it, what should be used instead "xxx" ?

```
typedef boost::mpl::transform
<
    Containers,
    boost::mpl::**xxx**<boost::mpl::_1 , int>
>::type IntContainers;
```

Answer (score 1):

[`transform`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/transform.html) takes an argument that needs to be a [Lambda Expression](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/lambda-expression.html). The simplest kind of lambda expression is a [Metafunction Class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/metafunction-class.html), so let's go with that. We need a class that has a nested class template named `apply` that yields a type named `type`. In our case, `apply` will take an "argument" that is itself a lambda expression (in our example `vector<_1>` and `<deque<_1>`) and we need to just [`apply`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/apply.html) it. That is:

```
template <typename Arg>
struct call_with {
    template <typename T>
    struct apply {
        using type = typename boost::mpl::apply<T, Arg>::type;
    };  
};

using R = boost::mpl::transform<
    Containers,
    call_with<int>
>::type;
```

It's probably possible to write all of `call_with` inline in `transform` with clever use of placeholders, but I find this a lot easier to understand.

**Edit** Apparently here's the clever use of placeholders:

```
using R = boost::mpl::transform<
    Containers,
    apply1<_1, int>
>::type;
```

I do not understand why `apply1` works where `apply` does not.